# Comparison based on Clojure types

Tags: clojure, functional-programming, predicates

I have the following record type that I am trying to test:

```
(defrecord FirstOrderState [datum matrix]
  State
  ;; implementation goes here ...
  )
```

I am trying to branch based on the above type, but am not getting the results I need

```
(def state (->FirstOrderState datum matrix))

(= (type state) composer.algorithm.markov.state.FirstOrderState)
=> false
```

However, looking at the type of `state` confirms that it should match:

```
(type state)
=> composer.algorithm.markov.state.FirstOrderState
```

This seems like it should work, as a similar check results in `true`:

```
(= (type []) clojure.lang.PersistentVector)
=> true
```

What is it that I am missing here? Using the below hack provides a solution, but not very elegant:

```
(= (str (type state)) (str composer.algorithm.markov.state.FirstOrderState))
=> true
```

Comment: So far I don't get it.  (Not that I know very much.)  It works when I try it with my own example.  What happens if you use `class` instead of `type`?

Comment: `class` doesn't work either -- from what I can tell, `class` is used for Java classes, and `type` is used for Clojure types. Fore example, if I try `(instance? state composer.algorithm.markov.state.FirstOrderState)`, I get an error stating that I can't coerce `state` to a Java class.

Comment: `class` and `type` usually produce the same result, but can be made to differ.  To see this, apply `class` in the `purchase-order` example on [this page](http://clojuredocs.org/clojure_core/clojure.core/type).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

My first guess would be that you have reloaded the namespace containing the definition of the record type *and* that `state` is defined elsewhere (possibly at the REPL), and so `composer.algorithm.markov.state.FirstOrderState` now refers to a different class from the one it used to at the time when `state` was created.

Demo at the REPL:

```
user=> (defrecord Foo [])
user.Foo
user=> (def foo (->Foo))
#'user/foo
user=> (= (type foo) Foo)
true
user=> (defrecord Foo [])
user.Foo
user=> (= (type foo) Foo)
false
```